# How to model a Time Series which has different nonstationary segments by ARIMA?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

I had a monthly river temperature (408 values, separated 360 for modeling). Then I deseasonalized and transformed it to a normal time series by a plotting position technique. Now I need to fit an ARMA model to the time series which I got. These plots show the time series which I want to fit a model, ACF and PACF plots.
[image]

According to the results I tried fitting ARMA(2,0,0) and ARIMA(1,0,1) using `arima(TS, c(2,0,0))` in R. but both models were very bad fit. For example, AR(2) results are like this (I just plotted a portion of results for a better view)
[image]

The only explanation that I can think of is this: the results of my `KPSS` test and `ADF` test is stationarity for whole data, but If I apply the test on the different portions of data (like last 50 or 70 values) it will result in nonstationarity. 
**So, Is my conclusion correct? or there is something else wrong with my modeling?
If I am right how can I model a time series which has different form of nonstationarity in different parts of the data?**
Thank you,

I attached the excel file of my time series in this link: [time series data (csv)](http://cl.ly/Nu6r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how you de-season your data before detrending? The ACF looks like there might still be a trend because the data shows a slow decay.

Also try using Breusch–Godfrey test or Ljung Box Q test to check for randomness in the ACF graph

I would adjust the parameters on the AR term q because the PACF has points passing the 95% CI

You can check how well the model fits using AICc

Answer (score -1):

[image: Short-time Furrier]

[image: Wavelet trnsf]

[image: garmonic jast 1 sin]
[image: Redfit spectr & 99% Monte Carlo CL]

Nice & transparent data... :-) There are strong 1st garmonic whith Period=12, ampl=6.4 and something else (noise & other...)

next jast got the residuals and fit sin-wave again...
[image: 3 sin-garmonics for res from T & 1st garmonic]
[image: wavelet spectr for res]

Comment: Welcome to the site @IvanKshnyasev. I wonder if this will be sufficiently self-explanatory to be useful for future readers, would you mind explicating this a bit?